# Decode base64 string sent by javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, base64, odoo

I'm trying to decode a string in Python sent by jQuery. I don't receive any error, but if I try to open the file, I get encoding error.

I'm trying to decode to save in ir.attachment in Odoo, but I think that's not the problem.

Currently, I remove 'data:image/jpeg;' at the start of the string sent by js.
I'm trying the following code:

```
base64.b64decode('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')
```

Comment: It will be difficult to help without a minimal reproducible example: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I add the first part of string! If I need to paste it all, how can I do it? I exceded maximun caracter per post.

Comment: Yes, but truncating the string makes it invalid base-64 in any case so we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added b64 encoding of ico!

Comment: your example base64 code is a png, not jpeg. If you really need to show larger amount of data, which can't be added to the post, you can use a link to https://pastebin.com/. But whenenver possible, it's better to include a small example directly instead of linking to pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works very well for me:

```
import base64


elem = base64.b64decode('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')

with open('test_save.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(elem)
```

Result:

[image]

Does it answer your question?

Comment: My problem was that I encode my string two times. Your post make me re-read my code and I solve it. Thanks!